# Many2many field related to another model

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I'm trying to create a many2many field inside a *Contact* model that would have the same values like `company_ids` inside a *Users* model at all times.

I was looking for the anwserws but the [odoo docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#related-fields) have like two sentences about this topic and do not explain this firmly.
Other sources seem to contradict themselfs because some says that related stored field do not update while other says that they do.

And after all I don't know the syntax for creating one myself because dosc are so poorly written.

I have this piece of code:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

class custom_partner_fields(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    company_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='res.company', string='Related users Allowed companies', readonly=True)
```

It is creating field inside *Contact* model and now I need something to fill it in. Preferably without using onchange methods or automatic actions (I have automatic action right now - created via developer UI).

Comment: Can you give one example what should be filled in? I really don't understand the requirement.

Comment: Model `Users` has the field `company_ids` that holds Allowed company for a particular User. For example UserA could have two allowed companies: CompanyX and CompanyY. I need to have this information also in `Contact` model so I could use it for a Record rule. Just simply copy the values from field inside Users to the field inside Contact.

Comment: It would not be necessary if I could access this user field from contact in other way but don't know how. It all comes down to the fact that contact model does not have just one id for related user but have weird one2many relation.

Comment: Can you explain, what you want to achieve with this record rule?

Comment: I want to change the global record rule for Contact so that it depends on Allowed companies rather than Current company. Here is the github issue I posted: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/35002 Now I just simply want to move my configuration inside the custom module. So I need to create that field with code and maybe change the way it gets its values (in other way that automatic action).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the field in partner record after creating or editing the user record

```py
      __inherit = 'res.users'


      @api.model
      def create(self, vals):
        res = super(TheClassName, self).create(vals)
        res.partner_id.company_ids = res.company_ids
        return res


      @api.multi
      def write(self, vals):
          super(TheClassName, self).write(vals)
          # if we edited company_ids we edit partners too
          if 'company_ids' in vals:
            # use mapped to call write one time good for performance
            self.mapped('partner_id').write({'company_ids': vals['company_ids']})
          return True
```

So when ever you edit `company_ids` in user you do the same for related partner.

This will work for new user for sure but I think you need to handle existing users
by a script or some solution to fill up the field.

Comment: It worked! Had some trouble with class names because I didn't know that class inside `super` should be the same as the my new class when overring the methods. I created class `Users` and used it also inside `super`.

Comment: And I solved the problem with existing users with [automated action](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16503469/61932571-096a0e00-af84-11e9-86c9-1bad2f517c96.png). With this automated action enabled I went to a users list, checked all of them and clicked _Unarchive_. This caused an update and triggered an automated action which filled my new field with values.

Comment: automated action very helpful features in did